# Running vba code beforesave despite read-only status

Tags: excel, readonly, excel-2016, before-save, vba

I've created an essentially blank workbook with lots of macros which loads data from variable sources ("Dashboard").  Using the `workbook_beforesave` event, I've hijacked the `Save` option into a function that saves the data as a separate .csv file, which can then be loaded into the workbook on opening.  The dashboard is stored on a shared drive, where the end-users can access it.  I have a test version and a live version.

The issue began when one of the end-users started leaving the dashboard open (locking it), and even somehow disabling events and saving over the blank workbook with their data.  Easy enough to restore from the test version, but annoying.

Setting the file to read-only on the server creates a host of unmitigatable issues (server is password protected, excel starts just asking for access credentials repeatedly).

My solution was inserting the following line in the workbook_open event:

```
If Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, 4) <> "TEST" Then ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
```

Which created another problem.  Now, when I click the `Save` button, the workbook_beforesave event doesn't fire until I've clicked `OK` on the "Can't save because it's read-only" notification, and then selected a folder to save it in.

DisplayAlerts does not get rid of the "Can't save" notification.

The question: Can I programmatically move directly into my save macro, dismissing the alert and avoiding the folder selection step?  Or do I need to create my own `Save` button and sidestep the issue entirely?

Comment: I think you need to change your approach.  Changing the "save" feature's built-in functionality might be quite a bit deeper than you expect, if it's even accessible.  You could introduce a "Export" button on a sheet or custom menu item.  or, depending on what you're trying to do, export on more frequent user actions, without them explicitly executing an export.

Comment: Yeah.  If this doesn't receive any answers I'm going to transfer my beforesave script to a macro and tie it to a button.  Then I'll just have a beforesave script that gives a warning along the lines of "Please use the save button in the workbook".  Mostly annoyed that displayAlerts won't suppress that message ...

Comment: You could always have save run the same script so if people hate adopting the button and don't mind the extra click then you're not alienating them.